# static asset serving from absolute path in play framework 2.3.x

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I need to serve image files from an absolute path that is not on the classpath. When I use `Assets.at(path, file)`, it only searches inside `/assets`. I have mapped the url onto a controller function like the following:

```
public static Action<AnyContent> getImage(String imageId) {
    String path = PICTURE_UPLOAD_DIR; // here this path is absolute
    String file = imageId + ".png";
    return Assets.at(path, file);
}
```

How can I make this work?

NOTE: The reason to make images served using `Assets` is because of the auto etagging feature that make easy to send http 304 not modified. It seems that there is no auto etagging feature that play provides independently from `Assets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets.at() works only for assets added to the classpath at build-time.
See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets

The solution would be to read the files from the disk as byte[] then return the byte[] in the response body.

**Converting the image to byte[]** (this solution is for small files only, for large files look into streams):

```
private static Promise<byte[]> toBytes(final File file) {
    return Promise.promise(new Function0<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public byte[] apply() throws Throwable {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

            for (int readNum; (readNum = is.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, readNum);
            }
            return os.toByteArray();
        }
    });
}
```

**The controller that uses toBytes() to serve the image:**

```
public static Promise<Result> img() {
    //path is sent as JSON in request body
    JsonNode path = request().body().asJson();

    Logger.debug("path -> " + path.get("path").asText());
    Path p = Paths.get(path.get("path").asText());
    File file = new File(path.get("path").asText());

    try {
        response().setHeader("Content-Type", Files.probeContentType(p));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.error("BUMMER!", e);
        return Promise.promise(new Function0<Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result apply() throws Throwable {
                return badRequest();
            }
        });
    }

    return toBytes(file).map(new Function<byte[], Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(byte[] bytes) throws Throwable {
            return ok(bytes);
        }       
    }).recover(new Function<Throwable, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
            return badRequest(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

**The route:**

```
POST    /img    controllers.YourControllerName.img()
```

#### If ETag support is needed:

(not adding Date or Last-Modified headers as they are not needed if ETag header is used instead):

**Get SHA1 for the file:**

```
private static Promise<String> toSHA1(final byte[] bytes) {       
    return Promise.promise(new Function0<String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply() throws Throwable {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byte[] digestResult = digest.digest(bytes);
            String hexResult = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < digestResult.length; i++) {
                hexResult += Integer.toString(( bytes[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
            }
            return hexResult;
        }
    });
}
```

**Setting the ETag headers:**

```
private static boolean setETagHeaders(String etag, String mime) {
    response().setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response().setHeader("ETag", "\"" + etag + "\"");
    boolean ifNoneMatch = false;

    if (request().hasHeader(IF_NONE_MATCH)) {
        String header = request().getHeader(IF_NONE_MATCH);
        //removing ""
        if (!etag.equals(header.substring(1, header.length() - 1))) {
            response().setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, mime);
        } 
        ifNoneMatch = true;
    } else {
        response().setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, mime);
    }
    return ifNoneMatch;
}
```

**Controller with ETag support:**

```
public static Promise<Result> img() {
    //path is sent as JSON in request body
    JsonNode path = request().body().asJson();
    Logger.debug("path -> " + path.get("path").asText());
    Path p = Paths.get(path.get("path").asText());
    File file = new File(path.get("path").asText());        
    final String mime;

    try {
        mime = Files.probeContentType(p);            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.error("BUMMER!", e);
        return Promise.promise(new Function0<Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result apply() throws Throwable {
                return badRequest();
            }
        });
    }
    return toBytes(file).flatMap(new Function<byte[], Promise<Result>>() {
        @Override
        public Promise<Result> apply(final byte[] bytes) throws Throwable {
            return toSHA1(bytes).map(new Function<String, Result>() {
                @Override
                public Result apply(String sha1) throws Throwable {
                    if (setETagHeaders(sha1, mime)) {
                        return status(304);
                    }
                    return ok(bytes);
                }
            });
        }
    }).recover(new Function<Throwable, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
            return badRequest(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

**A few drawbacks(there's always a BUT):**

1. This is blocking. So it's better to execute it on another Akka thread-pool configured for blocking IO.
2. As mentioned, the conversion to byte[] is for small files only, as it uses the memory for buffering. This should not be a problem in the case where you only serve small files(think web site grade images). See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html for different ways to read files using NIO2.

Comment: The reason I ask this question is to be able to use auto etagging static assets that is not inside `assets` folder. However, it seems that it's required to generate etag manually for images. So, could you add a solution to generate etag to static images?

Comment: In this case, please edit your question. I'll update the answer later.

Comment: Updated. For future reference: try to avoid changing the question. If it happens, you should create a separate post with a brand new question.

Comment: One more thing: you could have easily implemented the ETag support yourself, based on my initial answer. I'm not trying to bust your balls, but a little effort is in order now and then.

Comment: So, did you give the code a try?  All good? In need of more clarifications?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve this problem in a simpler way:

```
public static Result image(String image) {
  String basePath = "/opt/myapp/images";

  Path path = Paths.get(basePath + File.separator + image);
  Logger.info("External image::" + path);
  File file = path.toFile();
  if(file.exists()) {
    return ok(file);
  } else {
    String fallbackImage = "/assets/images/myimage.jpg";
    return redirect(fallbackImage);
  }
}
```

Route example:

```
GET     /image/:file    controllers.ExternalImagesController.image(file: String)
```

For large image files, you can use streaming.
Official docs can help you on that way.